# SwiftUI Login Issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I am making an app where I am using API to create login interface.

In my LoginViewModel class I have following login function

```
import Foundation
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginuser : Login?
    
    // func login(username: String, password: String, callback : @escaping (Bool,LoginData,String) -> Void) {
    func login(with params: [String: Any], completionHandler: @escaping (Bool,LoginData,String) -> Void) {
        //        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        //            "email": username,
        //            "password": password
        //        ]
        
        var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxx/v1//user/login")else {return}
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //request.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                semaphore.signal()
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            
        }//urlsession
        
        
        task.resume()
        
        
    }//login func

}
```

And in my view I have button whose action has following code

```
Button(action: {
                           
                            let params = ["email": userName,
                                          "password": password]
                            
                            
                            
                            viewModel.login(with: params) { success, data, message in
                               if success==true {
                                    UserDefaultsStore.isUserLoggedIn = true
                                   // UserDefaultsStore.loginuser = login
                                    showsAlert4 = true
                                    print ("cat1")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    
                                    print ("cat2")
                                    
                                }
                            }
                           
                        }, label: {
                            Image("btn_arrow")
```

While I can confirm the API is being read fine as console puts out data from this line in func login

```
 print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

What I can not get to work is show "cat1" or "cat2" message in case of successful or unsuccessful login attempt. In fact this piece of code just never executes

```
if success==true {
                                    UserDefaultsStore.isUserLoggedIn = true
                                   // UserDefaultsStore.loginuser = login
                                    showsAlert4 = true
                                    print ("cat1")
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    
                                    print ("cat2")
                                    
                                }
```

Any idea where I am going wrong in this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I have tried changing completionHandler: to callback: in func login but that changes nothing.

Comment: Your `completionHandler` is never called, and the callback never gets executed. You need to call it. Also, seems like you don't need `semaphore` at all

Comment: @Dialogue 
Can you please elaborate on how to implement and call completionHandler in my code?

Comment: Convert your code to async/await. Read Apple's documentation here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/

Comment: I am new in this area that is why I am having hard time solving this issue. I will be grateful if you can modify my code so that I understand it better for future

Comment: > Dialogue Can you please elaborate on how to implement and call completionHandler in my code?

@bushra, below is the answer from ungur-maria is implementing exactly what I've described

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments mentioned, you are not calling your `completionHandler` at all. You could also drop the semaphore as it is not needed. Or maybe I am missing the point of the semaphore and you can elaborate on that.

```
import Foundation
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var loginuser : Login?

func login(with params: [String: Any], completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, LoginData?, String) -> Void) {
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxx/v1//user/login")else {return}
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            semaphore.signal()
            completionHandler(false, nil, "Error") -> ON FAILURE
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        // The next line will work only if the struct LoginData is Decodable. Make sure to make it Decodable
        if let loginData = try? decoder.decode(LoginData, from: data) {
            completionHandler(true, loginData, "") -> ON SUCCESS
        } else {
            // We have a decoding error
            completionHandler(false, nil, "Error while decoding")
        }
    
    
    task.resume()
    
    
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. When I implement this, on line

completionHandler(false, nil, "Error")

I get this error

'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'LoginData'

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can either declare the completion handler as this `@escaping (Boo l, LoginData?, String)` (notice how I declared the LoginData as optional) or another option would be to pass `LoginData()` like a dummy object because it's going to be an error anyway so you don't care what you have there. I strongly suggest the version with passing nil and declaring as Optional (LoginData?)

Comment: Let me know if this worked and also would appreciate an accepted answer if it worked ;)

Comment: Thanks Ungur. While LoginData? did the trick, now Xcode is throwing error on this line success line completionHandler(true, data, "")

Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'LoginData?'

What should I do for this?

Comment: You need to decode the data. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for updating the code Maria. I implemented it and now have another issue. 

This always results in bypassing else block even if invalid password is given. 

            guard  let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                completionHandler(false, nil, "Error")
                semaphore.signal()
                return
            }
In other words, data is always = data that's why else is never triggered. Xcode console does give message of user credentials wrong. not sure what is going on. Can you help in this regard please?

Comment: I think this is over my power because I need to see the request and the response. Maybe a thing to add would be to check if the error is nil like `guard error != nil, let data = data else {` to see if there is an error returned, which it should be

Comment: the error is always returning nil whether credentials are correct or not. Can you check the request and response in postman to help me please? https://dev.thetechub.us/karma/public/api/v1//user/login